# Styling body element in react without overriding the body on my other components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, forms, css-animations

I have five-page folders. each folder has a CSS file and a js file. each js file is importing a component. that component is wrapped in the CSS class name. every time I try to style using an element like body or form, my styling on all other pages is overridden.

the only way I can style the body is by putting the styling in a class and wrapping it around the component. there has to be a better way. I'm trying to animate my screen and it takes a lot of styling elements directly.

````
import LandingPageComponent from "../../components/LandingPageComponent"

function LandingPage(){
    return(
        <div className=".landingpage">
            <LandingPageComponent />
        </div>
    )
}

export default LandingPage; ```
````

Comment: The first error what i can see is that you have referenced tha selector ```landingpage``` of css in the class Name element with ```.landingpage.``` when you reference any selector of a css, you don't have to write with ```.``` so remove ```.``` before landingpage.

Comment: That's my fault for not mentioning.  I have a class that I named landing page that I'm using to style the body since I can't style body directly.  In my css file .landingpage contains a screen height, background color, and other minor stylings